# Unikong credit screen not reacting to spacebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, unikong

I've just opened Unikong, and looked at the credits. The legend on the start screen tells you that you could use <kbd>Space</kbd> to press buttons, but this doesn't work on the button that lets you leave the credit screen. The only way out was to use <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead (which works on the other buttons as well, but is not documented so far).

Comment: @Downvoter: Am I missing freehand circles?

Comment: I think the controls is for playing and not how to navigate.

Comment: Oh yeah... forgot to bind it there. Ah well. =)

Comment: @Rizier123: Does it matter? Navigation works with clicks, enter, and space bar …except on the credit screen.

Comment: @AdamLear This is a travesty. Clearly not ready for release. Another game rushed to market before it was ready. When will the gaming industry learn. Etc.

Comment: @meagar - you have a point. We will pull it out in a day or so, after collecting more feedback.

Comment: Valve made a similar mistake with their Monster clicker game on Steam. It proved fatal and was pulled within weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I've patched the code and it's now live. Credits now react to spacebar as you'd hope.

Comment: Wonderful. You really should credit the SO community for gamma testing :-)